# Chef how to run a run list in filtered node

Tags: knife, chef

How to run a run list in several nodes?
Now I wrote a script loop those severs and run using knife bootstrap.
Is there better way to do it? 
Like how we use "knife ssh 'id:*', can we run a run list in filtered server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "knife ash" to run "chef-client" on each found server with a custom run_list, http://docs.opscode.com/chef/chef_client.html has an option to override the run list using "-o".